# Not getting expected results from wikipedia by using Bliki

Tags: java, wikipedia-api, bliki

I'm using `Bliki-core` (version-3.1.0) to access a wikipedia page with the the title "Web service" for my test case. My code is below

```
String[] listOfTitleStrings = { "Web service" };
User user = new User("", "", "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php");
user.login();
List<Page> listOfPages = user.queryContent(listOfTitleStrings);
for (Page page : listOfPages) {
    WikiModel wikiModel = new WikiModel("${image}", "${title}");
    String html = wikiModel.render(page.toString());
    System.out.println(html);
}
```

When i access the URL:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
>   format=xml&action=query&titles=Web%20service&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

I can see the xml output.
But when I run my java code i get the following output

```
<p>Page{ns=0, title=Web service, id=93483, links=[], categories=[],
editToken=&#39;null&#39;, imageUrl=&#39;null&#39;, imageThumbUrl=&#39;null&#39;, 
missing=false, invalid=false, revision=info.bliki.api.Revision@74e46064}</p>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I'm just speculating, but what happen if you change https:// to http:// in your User instantiation?

Comment: if i change to http from https, then on running program nothing happens and output is blank

Comment: Your code seems to be right. Do you have all dependencies on bliki-core? [bliki-core dependencies](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki/wiki/Mediawiki2HTML), also make sure that your projects text file encoding is UTF-8 if you use Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing version of bliki-core to an earlier version 3.0.19 fixed the issue.